# Flex order property, screen readers and accessibility

Tags: html, css, flexbox, accessibility, voiceover

I have a link as parent with `display: flex` and all children have different order with css.

With NVDA when the focus is on the link, the screen reader read all content following the DOM order.

On Mac with VoiceOver, the screenreader follow the order on the screen and not the DOM order.

How can i fix it?

```css
a {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  order: 0;
}
h2 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div>
    <span>€ 300</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

On windows, on focus i get: Title 300€ 
On Mac, on focus i get: 300€ Title

Answer (score 11):

You can't fix this.

Any media, other than visual, that adheres to the `order` rules is non-conforming. You rely on non-conforming implementations at your own risk (i.e., the behavior can change at any time).

*From the flexbox specification:*

> [**5.4.1. Reordering and
>   Accessibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-accessibility)
>
> The `order` property does not affect ordering in non-visual media
>   (such as speech). Likewise, `order` does not affect the default
>   traversal order of sequential navigation modes (such as cycling
>   through links, see e.g. tabindex).
>
> Authors must use `order` only for visual, not logical, reordering of
>   content. Style sheets that use `order` to perform logical reordering
>   are non-conforming.
>
> Note: This is so that non-visual media and non-CSS UAs, which
>   typically present content linearly, can rely on a logical source
>   order, while order is used to tailor the visual order. (Since visual
>   perception is two-dimensional and non-linear, the desired visual order
>   is not always logical.)
>
> [read
>   more...](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-accessibility)