# Text selection problem when using Flexbox order in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I ran into an issue when using flexbox and it's ordering of elements using `order`.

Example:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    
      <div style="order: 4">this is some paragraphs</div>
      <div style="order: 3">this is another paragraph</div>
      <div style="order: 2">this may be phone number</div>
      <div style="order: 1">this may be firstname</div>
      <div style="order: 0">just a random </div>
      
    </div>
```

In the example above, the flex container is used to reorder `<div>` elements to desired order. The problem is when the user is trying to select the paragraphs using mouse (when trying to copy paste the paragraphs for example) it behaves very weirdly, it's not possible to fully select all paragraphs and the copy-pasted text is in original order.

Is there a way to prevent it from happening? To make it behave like the paragraphs were in that order naturally? Like DOM ordering instead of 'visual' only? A different approach?

Comment: why not just simply use `flex-direction: column-reverse`? In any case, as it is reversed you need also to select them in a reversed order from top-right to bottom-left

Comment: @tacoshy doesn't appear to change the behavior when trying to select text, at least not for me in a chromium-based browser. And taking https://stackoverflow.com/a/49033753/1427878 into account, I think this might not be fixable in any other way but to _actually_ change the DOM order.

Comment: @tacoshy the fact that in the provided example the elements are exactly in the reverse order is just coincidence. The order is in my real scenario more-or-less random.