Text selection on flex reverse-column child happened in wrong direction
I'm trying to select text in flex reverse-column container but actual selection is wrong. Browser attempts to make selection from end of the element, that leads to wrong selection.
Example,


<div style="flex-direction: column-reverse; display: flex;">
  <div>1 wwww</div>
  <div>2 wwww</div>
  <div>
    3 wwww
    <br/>
    4 wwww
  </div>
  <div>5 wwww</div>
</div>



try to select from left top corner to the center of the text.

Expected: 5 wwww 3 wwww 4 ww is selected. Actual: ww is selected.

I don't fix you can "fix" this, since Flexbox doesn't change the actual DOM. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032790/flex-order-property-screen-readers-and-accessibility/49033753#49033753

Is there way to maintain natural selection for user without removing column-reverse. Using selection api or somehow else

since the reversed appearence is fighting against their actual order when selecting text, a solution to your problem might(!) be to just reverse their order in the DOM instead of using the css strategy.  In that case you should run [...document.getElementById(containerId).children].reverse().forEach(child => container.appendChild(child)); on DOMContentLoaded. But this is a workaround

Because you are using br tag inside the "3 wwww" div. That's why the issue occurs. Try this instead of br tag:


<div style="flex-direction: column-reverse; display: flex;">
  <div>1 wwww</div>
  <div>2 wwww</div>
  <div>
    3 wwww
  </div>
  <div>
    4 wwww
  </div>
  <div>5 wwww</div>
</div>



